# Anyone programming using Necessitas (Qt for Android)?

Tags: android, qt, dalvik

I am working with Necessitas (Qt for Android). All run fine.

Now, I am trying to connect to the Dalvik JVM to use some of the Android API (GPS for example). To do this I'm trying to get the Java environment using JNI:

```
JNIEnv *currEnv;
currEnv = 0;
if (m_javaVM->GetEnv((void**)&currEnv,JNI_VERSION_1_4) == JNI_OK)
{
    qDebug() << "GetEnv passed";
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "GetEnv failed";
}
```

`m_javaVM` is the pointer to the virtual machine used by Necessitas.

The problem is that I always get GetEnv failed when I run the application in the android virtual device.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I want to do the same work just like you (GPS), but i am a Newb, Can you share your way to use JNI ? thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my ow question:

This happens because getEnv gets the current env. While what i need to to get a new env with something like:

```
if (currVM->AttachCurrentThread((void **)&currEnv, NULL)<0)
        {
            emit error("Cannot attach the current thread to the VM");
        }
```